# Google Sheets: Search for matching text within two columns across multiple sheets and return sheet title upon correct match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19aehKQ_B_XfnG245kz2o2X98PE-JMtqnws4A0RFnskk/edit?usp=sharing)

Hi, I'm new to using formulas in sheets so I apologize for what is most likely a common question, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

Basically, I have a master sheet filled with the names of various institutions in column B, groups of these institutions belong to different clusters as indicated in the additional sheets of the example I've posted. I need a way so that when the institution's names match, they append either the sheet name or simply the string "Cluster 01", "Cluster 02", etc. to column A. Also, if there are no matches to be found, I'd like it to return as a blank cell.

Thanks in advance!

I previously tried

```
=if(VLOOKUP('Cluster 01'!B4:B6,B4:B13,1,FALSE),"Cluster 01")
```

But this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, nor does it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with XLOOKUP:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(B2:B,{'Cluster 01'!B:B;'Cluster 02'!B:B},{'Cluster 01'!A:A;'Cluster 02'!A:A},,0))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this. This works perfectly for what I need it for, you've saved me hours of time!